# kubeadm token create with Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on bare metal and I'm writing an Ansible task to get the join command from a master node:

```
- name: Get join command from master
  shell: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
  when: role == "master"
  run_once: true
  register: join_command
```

When I run the playbook, I got the following error: "unable to create bootstrap token after 5 attempts []".

If I run the exact same command (`kubeadm token create --print-join-command`) directly on the master host or remotely using `ssh kube-master kubeadm token create --print-join-command`, it outputs the join command correctly.

I've ran out of options here... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can get that error if your "kubeadm" cannot connect to the Kubernetes cluster using credentials from the configuration file. You can reproduce it by stopping the `docker` service on your master node.

There is no difference between running the command using Ansible or shell in your case, so it should work.

So, the only things I can suggest are:

1. Verify that the Ansible role `master` is attached to the right host.
2. Check if the Ansible user has access to the `kubeadm` configuration, its default path is `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`, and make sure that configuration is right. You might try to run the command as root using the `become: true` option.

Comment: In my case, `kubelet` wasn't running because there was swap space on the server after a reboot. Neither Ansible nor the command run directly on the server worked. Once I disabled swap the command worked in both places.

Answer (score 0):

There was a proxy configuration set in the ansible playbook:

```
---

- hosts: [vmsk8s]
  roles:
    - vmsk8s
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://10.0.0.1:3128
    https_proxy: http://10.0.0.1:3128
```

Removing the proxy environment vars fixed the problem.